# latexdiff file not found on include figure.tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfiles, latexdiff

I am running `latexdiff --flatten main.tex main.tex > new.tex` to produce a document with all the `input`, `include` and `subfile` LaTeX files included. The goal is to then do the same with an older version so that I can finally run `latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex` to generate a PDF which shows all the differences between the two versions, including those in the subfiles.

However, `latexdiff` trips up over `\input{figures/example.tikz}` with a file not found error:

`Couldn't open ./figures/example.tikz.tex: No such file or directory at /opt/local/bin/latexdiff line 1105.`

I believe the issue is that `latexdiff` appends `.tex` unless there is a 3 character file extension on the file. However, the files are `.tikz` which is 4 characters!

How can I get `latexdiff` to find and include correct file here?

Comment: Tedious solution: rename all your diagram files to have the `.tex` extension.

Comment: That's a possibility, however it's all in git, so the old version will need checking out and editing too, which doubles the tedium!

Comment: I can't reproduce the error (the `.tikz` file is properly included) with `LATEXDIFF 1.1.1  (Algorithm::Diff 1.15 fast, Perl v5.24.1) (c) 2004-2015 F J Tilmann`.

Comment: I have `LATEXDIFF 1.2.1  (Algorithm::Diff 1.1903, Perl v5.24.2)` on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `latexdiff` version 1.2.1 the `.tex` extension is indeed added for files without a three letter extension. In previous versions this check was defined as `$fname =~ m|\.\w{3}|` (a period followed by three letters *somewhere* in the filename), which was too permissive, and was changed to `$fname =~ m|\.\w{3}$|` (a period followed by three letters *at the end* of the filename).

This check is intended for the use of `\input{myfile}` to input `myfile.tex`, which is allowed in LaTeX. However, the check is too strict for files with different length extensions, or no extension at all. As a workaround you can change the source code of `latexdiff`, within `sub flatten` (around line 1800 in version 1.2.1) from

```perl
$fname .= ".tex" unless $fname =~ m|\.\w{3}$|;
```

to

```perl
$fname .= ".tex" unless $fname =~ m|\.\w{3}$| || -e File::Spec->catfile($dirname,$fname);
```

which states that the filename is changed unless it has a three letter extension or the filename as provided points to an existing file.

There are two lines in the sub where this should be changed (the `input`/`include`/`includeonly` part and the `subfile` part). Save the file over the original in the system folder or save a modified copy locally and execute the local version (`./latexdiff`).

---

Note that in the current version of `latexdiff` on GitHub (1.2.2a, https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff) the regular expression accepts 3 or 4 letter extensions (`$fname =~ m|\.\w{3,4}$|`). This solves the issue of the OP, but for other cases (e.g., 2 or 5 letter extensions, or no extension at all) the workaround in this answer can still be used.

Comment: There is into my question my thank you for your edit my question.